# Spring Boot - application.yml, read value from a file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, application.properties

I have a property present in application.yml but the value of that property is present in another file. Over here `username` is present in file `/etc/app/db_username`

```
database:
   url: localhost:14482
   username: /etc/app/db_username
   password: /etc/app/db_password
```

Is there a way I can have values of username and password from the file automatically instead of me reading the file.

```
@Value("${database.username}")
String username; //Will give me /etc/app/db_username

@Value("${database.password}")
String password; //Will give me /etc/app/db_password
```

Comment: Can you not use environment variables instead of files? https://12factor.net/config

Comment: @OneCricketeer Cannot do it for whole other reason.

Comment: I don't remember offhand how to do it for YAML files, but the Spring concept you're looking for is called `PropertySource`.

Comment: are you looking for this : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml-propertysource ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [@ConfigurationProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.3/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationProperties.html) for this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConstructorBinding;

@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties("database")
public class DatabaseConfig {
    private final String username;
    private final String password;

    public DatabaseConfig(Path username,
                          Path password) throws IOException {
        this.username = Files.readString(username);
        this.password = Files.readString(password);
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
}
```

You need to place a `@EnableConfigurationProperties(DatabaseConfig.class)` on one of your configuration classes (or the `@SpringBootApplication` itself) for this to work.

A complete example on GitHub (with Gradle 7, Java 11 and Spring-Boot 2.5.3): https://github.com/jannis-baratheon/stackoverflow--spring-boot-configurationproperties-file-reading

Comment: Thanks a lot for spending time and writing small app for to solve this issue. Unfortunately you still have to manually read from the file.

Comment: @gsm1986 You have to read the file this way or another - you want the contents of the file after all. How would you define "non-manual" way of doing this? I don't think it gets any simpler.